# Should estimates over a subsample be similar to the full sample when using panel data?

Tags: regression, panel-data

I am estimating the effect of $x$ on $y$;  $y$ and $x$ are available both by city and by year.  During the first period, $T_1$, both $x$ and $y$ generally increase.  During the second period, $T_2$, both generally decrease.  I have about 30 cities over 40 years.

1. How can I use regression to attribute the average effect of $x$ on $y$ to the overall average increase in $y$ during $T_1$ and the same for the decrease in $T_2$?  For example, I want to say something like during period $T_1$, $x$ can explain 5% of the increase in $y$ over $T_1$.  How would I compute $x$?  Normally, I divide the coefficient by the average difference between the last year and the first year, but that approach does not sound sensible if $x$ and $y$ both increase and then decrease.
2. I find statistically significant results when I do the regression over the entire time period.  However, if I break it separately to just subperiods, $T_1$ and $T_2$, neither are statistically significant and the coefficients change sign.  Is that simply because the smaller sample makes the standard errors blow up?  Should I find effects of $x$ and $y$ over subsamples of the panel?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would want to figure out within- and between- regression, which might give different results. Abusing a popular example of an external cause of an apparently spurious correlation between two variables, suppose you have number of students in universities vs. outside temperature, by week, throughout the year, across a large country such as the US. The between-university regression will say that there is no relation between temperature and attendance (unless for some reason the schools in warmer climate are consistently larger or smaller than those in cold climate), while within-university regression will tell you that the warmer it is outside, the fewer students you will find in the audience (hint: the enrollments are generally lower in the summer, the hottest time of the year). These two regressions thus respond to different drivers, and that's what you seem to be interested in.

[Wooldridge 2010](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262232588) is a great book on panel data that I would strongly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

When using the full sample, your estimate is a weighted average of the effects in the two periods. Unless the effect is the same in both periods, a regression using the full sample will give different results than regressions for each subsample. I had a concrete example of this in my paper "[Broken or Fixed Effects?](http://cgibbons.berkeley.edu/Research/Papers/Gibbons--FixedEffects.pdf)" with two coauthors, but, unfortunately, it had to be cut. The principles discussed therein, however, are just as applicable to your situation. Your fixed effects would be a time period dummy.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond!  I do not understand how to implement your suggested approach.  Also, I do not understand whether you think I am better off using the normal fixed effects with the full sample or separately over the subsamples.  I know if I only use the subsamples, that I may have limited statistical power.  At the same time, I want to answer the first question in my initial inquiry, and I am not sure how to do that over the full sample (explaining how much x contributed to y in the first subsample)

Comment: $R^2$ tells you the fraction of the variation in $y$ that can be predicted using $x$. That seems to be the statistic that you're looking for. Run a regression of $y$ on $x$ and $x$ multiplied by a dummy indicating whether you are in time period 1 or not, plus the period 1 dummy itself. Technically, this would measure how well knowing $x$ and the time period improve your prediction of $y$. For just the impact of $x$, regress $y$ on an intercept and the time period dummy. Then, regress the residuals from that regression on $x$ and $x$ times the time period dummy.

Comment: As to our solution, we have a Stata command that I can share if you use that program.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, but I'm not sure that is what I'm looking to say.  This is what I want to say.  Let's say time period 1 is 1960 to 1980 and time period 2 is 1981 to 2000.  Suppose the dependent variable increases by 10% from 1960 to 1980 but then it decreases by 5% from 1981 to 2000.  I want to know how much the variable of interest, conditional on all of the covariates, explain the increase in y from 1960 to 1980 and then decreases it from 1981 to 2000.  If I was only doing the regression from 1960 to 1980, I divide the regression coefficient by say the 10%.  Is that wrong?

Comment: We typically don't think about regression that way. We think about the predictor $x$ changing and ask how much $y$ changes. Run your regress, get a prediction of $y$ in 1960 based upon the values of your predictors from that year, get the prediction from 1980 in the same manner, then take the difference. This is the change in the conditional expected value. You can divide this figure by the actual change from 1960 to 1980, but there's no reason why this ratio must be between 0 and 1. Predictions at any single point in time can overshoot or undershoot; you just hope to be right on average.

Comment: I have to think about that some more.  I was thinking about your solution and Stata code.  With regular fixed effects, are you arguing that there is normally a linear assumption on the fixed effects but that it is restrictive?  Does your estimator do something more nonparametric that fits to the data?  I guess I'm confused about how it fits to the different subperiods differently and how it is a better fit?

Comment: The assumption that we are challenging is that the treatment effect is the same for each fixed effects group (for you, each time period). We allow the estimated effect to be different for each group.

Comment: Do the fixed effects still enter into the function as dummies?  I'm sorry that I'm not understanding this.  I really appreciate your patience with me.  Please let me know if it would be better to hash this out over a chat room here, if you do not mind.

Comment: Fixed effects are just a set of dummy variables.

Comment: I don't understand what your method does that is different from a current standard OLS regression.  Let's say I'm using Stata.  I could do reg y x i.year where i.year gives the dummy variable for each year.  That assumes a constant treatment effect over each year?  What does your method do?

Comment: We essentially do `reg y i.year*x`. This regresses $y$ on $x$, year fixed effects, and an interaction between $x$ and the year fixed effects. Standard fixed effects regressions allow different intercepts for each group; our method allows for different slopes (for $x$) for each group.